# How to execute exceeded length query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The character string that starts with '"0111" OR "0112" OR "0115" OR ' is too long. Maximum length is 4000.

```
declare @stmt1 varchar(max)
set @stmt1='insert into dbo.abcd SELECT [company],[address], 
[address2],[zip],[zip4],[city],[state], 
[telephone_number],LOWER([email]),[name],[fname],[mname],[lname], 
[title_full] FROM DBO.filter WHERE  
[id] in (''7'',''8'',''11'',''15'')  and contains 
(code,'+''''+'"0111" OR "4142"......................OR 
"5999"'+''''+')'
exec (@stmt1) AT [server]
```

Comment: what is the exact error messages ?

Comment: What happened with the last two times you've asked this question? varchar(max) length limit is 2GB. If your length limit is 4000 chars, you're doing something wrong. The code you've provided is not enough to answer this question.

Comment: make two or more same queries instead of one and distribute values of IN among them. Run a while loop and execute all queries until all the queries are executed.

Comment: `<contains_search_condition>` [does not allow max datatypes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) max length is `nvarchar(4000)`

Comment: You can insert your filter codes to a physical table first and then use `IN(SELECT Code FROM MyCodeTable)` instead of the long list. If there are concurring actions you can add an `ActionID` to you table, insert the codes together with this value and add this to the SELECT within the IN-clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @stmt1 varchar(max)
set @stmt1=CAST('insert into dbo.abcd SELECT [company],[address], 
[address2],[zip],[zip4],[city],[state], 
[telephone_number],LOWER([email]),[name],[fname],[mname],[lname], 
[title_full] FROM DBO.filter WHERE  
[id] in (''7'',''8'',''11'',''15'')  and contains 
(code,' AS VARCHAR(MAX))+''''+'"0111" OR "4142"......................OR 
"5999"'+''''+')'


exec (@stmt1) AT [server]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your codes list are stored in a table, say 'dbo.codes', with a field 'code' containing the value, you can avoid the CONTAINS predicate and use an INNER JOIN between the two tables using LIKE.

```
DECLARE @stmt1 VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @stmt1 = 'INSERT INTO dbo.abcd
SELECT DISTINCT [F].[company], [F].[address], [F].[address2], [F].[zip], [F].[zip4],
[F].[city], [F].[state], [F].[telephone_number], LOWER([F].[email]),
[F].[name], [F].[fname], [F].[mname], [F].[lname], [F].[title_full]
FROM dbo.filter AS F INNER JOIN dbo.codes AS C ON F.code LIKE ''%'' + C.code + ''%''
WHERE (F.id in (''7'',''8'',''11'',''15''))';
EXEC (@stmt1) AT [server]
```